# Writing pop and push functions for Haskell stack

Tags: haskell, stack

Hi I'm trying to create pop and push functions for a Haskell stack defined like this :

```
data mystack = Empty | Elem Char mystack deriving Show
```

If I didn't have this definition restriction I would do push like this

```
push x mystack = (x:mystack)
```

and pop like this

```
pop mystack = head mystack
```

But with this restriction I don't know how to implement these functions.
Can you give me some hint how to do these please? 
I even couldn't write a Stack type with that description myself.

Comment: You most definitely need to read [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#recursive-data-structures)

Comment: You also need to check your identifiers. Tokens that follow the `data` keyword should start with a capital letter: `data MyStack = Empty | Elem Char MyStack deriving (Show)`

Comment: ps, you may not realise it but you've actually just re-defined the built-in list. `MyStack` is the same as `[Char]` (which is the same as `String`), just with differently-named value constructors.

Comment: Now I can write Stacks like Elem 'a' Elem 'b' Empty.
I tried to write push function like this :
`push x Empty = Element x`
`push x MyStack = Element x MyStack`
it didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't that read `push x Empty = Elem x Empty`, and `push x mystack = Elem x mystack`? (Also, the first of those two equations is redundant)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: here is how you might implement your stack operations using the built-in list:

```
push :: a -> [a] -> ((),[a])  -- return a tuple containing a 'nothing' and a new stack
push elem stack = ((), (:) elem stack)

pop :: [a] -> (a, [a])  -- return a tuple containing the popped element and the new stack
pop [] = error "Can't pop from an empty stack!"
pop ((:) x stack) = (x, stack)
```

`(:) x xs` is an alternative way of writing `x:xs`.

To do this on your own `MyStack` type, note that your `Empty` actually works just like `[]`, and `Elem` is equivalent to `(:)`. I won't give you the code to do this outright, because figuring it out for yourself is half the fun!

Comment: The relationship might be a bit more obvious if you use `(:)` rather than the infix `:` to show that the `:` is just a data constructor, the same as `Elem`, even though the syntax is a little different.

Comment: Thank you, your hints really helped a lot. I figured it out finally :)

Comment: When I write the function like this:
`push :: Char -> Stack ->Stack
push  x Empty = (Element x Empty)
push   x  stack = (Element x stack) `
I get error for this input : `push 'a' Element 'b' Empty`
I get this output  `Element 'a' (Element 'b' Empty)`
For this input `push 'a' (Element 'b' Empty)`
How can I get this output : `Element 'a' Element 'b' Empty` for this input: `push 'a' Element 'b' Empty`
Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Your function is behaving as it should. You need brackets around the second argument to `push`. That's just how Haskell's syntax is designed.